# Read certificate purposes

Tags: windows, delphi, ssl-certificate, smartcard, pki

My users have a PKI card and a card reader. There is a private key on the PKI card and they must install the associated certificate. Certificate must be selected in the application and this is where the problem arises because some people choose the wrong certificate.

**The question is how to read certificate purposes ?** I need this line: **Smart Card Logon**.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I tried:
CertGetCertificateContextProperty
CertOpenStore

and few other function but without success.

Comment: Hello, did you know [delphiopenssl](https://github.com/zizzo81/delphiopenssl)? and the exemple https://github.com/zizzo81/delphiopenssl/blob/master/example5.md

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetenhancedkeyusage

Comment: You can find the OID to look for in the Extended Key Usage (EKU) here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/15549/2651. The presence of the OID in the EKU is almost certainly simply translated into that string by the code that reads the cert...